# mocha testing nodejs mssql - connection is closed

Tags: sql-server, node.js, mocha.js

Trying to setup my tests for NodeJS with MsSql using Mocha. But every time I run my tests I get a "Connection is closed".

[image]

The weird thing is that it does work when I run the app in itself, then, I do get the data back from the database and the connection isn't closed too soon.

My code for the test:

```
var express = require('express');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var calendar = require('./../Server/calendarDatabase');

describe("Calendar", function () {
    describe("Database", function () {
        it("should get stuff from the database", function (done) {
            calendar.getAll().then(function (returnValue) {
                console.dir(returnValue);
                expect(returnValue.count).to.equal(5);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

What my calendarDatabase code looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = require('./../config');

var calendarDbConnection = {};

sql.connect(config.mssql, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

calendarDbConnection.getAll = function () {
    return new sql.Request()
        .query('select * from Human')
        .then(function (recordsets) {
        return recordsets;
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}

module.exports = calendarDbConnection;
```

And finally, this is what I use when running the app:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var calendarDb = require('./../Server/calendarDatabase');

router.get("/", function (request, response) {
    response.render('calendar', { title: 'Calendar app title' });
});

router.get('/getYear/:year', function (request, response) {
    calendarDb.getAll().then(function(returnValue) {
        console.dir(returnValue);
    });
    response.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

So my question, why does this not work while testing with Mocha but it does when running the app in itself? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My connection seemed to be closed because of the framework not keeping it open.
Making my connection a promise worked.

```
describe("Calendar", function () {
    describe("Database", function () {
        it("should get stuff from the database", function (done) {
            calendar.Connect().then(function () {
                calendar.getAll().then(function (returnValue) {
                    console.dir(returnValue);
                    expect(returnValue.count).to.equal(5);
                }).done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Calendar db:

```
calendarDbConnection.Connect = function() {
    return sql.connect(config.mssql);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for awhile, and was either breaking mocha testing, breaking my api functionality, or breaking pooling. Ended up using the following code using callbacks with successful pooling.

First I made a file in root called sql.js

```
var config = require('./config.js');
var sql = require('mssql');
var cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config.sql);

const connect = function(callback) {

    if(cp.connected) {
        callback(cp);

        return true;

    }

    cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config.sql, function() {
        callback(cp);

    });

}

module.exports = {
    connect

}
```

Then within any controller, I simply include the module sql and reference it like so

```
var sql = require('../../sql.js');

const someFunction = (callback) => {

    sql.connect(function(cp) {
        cp.request()
        .input('jti', jti)
        .input('reference', reference)
        .execute('insertToken', function (err, recordset) {
            callback(err, recordset);

        });

    })

}
```